# How do i mirror loop cuts?

Tags: modeling

I want to mirror my loop cuts, not the whole object. Like when you tug an edge when edge modeling. I have tried but found no solution.

Comment: Maybe do a single loop cut in the middle then bevel it to create the two loops? Difficult to tell without an image of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the half of the mesh that doesn't have the loop cuts, and then add the mirror modifier.